# images visible on responsive mobile/tablets but hidden on desktop

Tags: html, css, desktop, hidden

I have a fluid grid website that I'm designing using DW CS6. I am trying place a click to call image and a click to text image that I want to function only on a mobile device. I know that it is possible to have images and text hidden on certain size devices but I am not knowledgeable enough to understand how. I have tried to add the screen size limitations at the bottom of my CSS but that did not work either. I do have the code working to text or call from a mobile device. :)

Would I create a div class id="mobile"? I would greatly appreciate any direction that could be given. I have the media queries that come standard with the Fluid Grid Template in  DW CS6.

HTML

```
<a href="tel:2513676152"><img src="images/callme.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="click to call"></a>
<a href="sms:2513676152"><img src="images/textme.jpg" width="100" height="100" a;t="click to text"></a>
```

CSS

```
/*
    Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
    ----------------------------------
    dw-num-cols-mobile:     5;
    dw-num-cols-tablet:     8;
    dw-num-cols-desktop:    10;
    dw-gutter-percentage:   25;



/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */
.gridContainer {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:87.36%;
    padding-left:1.82%;
    padding-right:1.82%;
}

#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.gridContainer {
    width:90.675%;
    padding-left:1.1625%;
    padding-right:1.1625%;
}

#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.gridContainer {
    width:88.2%;
    max-width:1232px;
    padding-left:0.9%;
    padding-right:0.9%;
    margin:auto;
}

#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
}
```

Comment: What are the media-queries that you're using currently?

Comment: So your question is, how to hide the images on your phone? Or how to make them visible on your computer?

Comment: I'd like to hide them on desktop only. As it is now, the click to call and the click to text buttons are visible on both a mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add media queries to your CSS to be able to accomplish this

```
/* DESKTOP CODE HERE */

@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    /* MOBILE CODE HERE */
}
```

Comment: Thank you Diana. Sadly, I only know the media queries that come with the template from DW. Do you know where I could find the information to learn how to use the media queries for visible/hidden?

Comment: If you add `display:none;` to the classes or id that you don't want to appear on Desktop you'll be able to do it. For example outside the media screen queries: img{display:none;} this will disable all images on desktop, now create this to the classes you don't want to appear on desktop

Comment: Glad I could help @KrissieC :) If you have some time a voting or marking my answer as correct is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

within your code you provided you have different media queries. The last one is for desktop. When the screen width is over 768 px, this media query is being used for certain styles. So within this query, you would use your "display:none" or "visibility:hidden"(depends on what effect you want to achieve) to not show the image.

Example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) { 
    .yourimgclass{display:none; (or) visibility:hidden;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. I created a  div class="mobile" in the HTML and added .mobile { display:none;} to the CSS and all is working. Thank y'all so much for the guidance.